# laravel model chunk with column condition and update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

table `tname` like below:

`id    name    status
1     name1     0
2     name2     0
3     name3     0
4     name4     0`

I create a model for the table above named `Tname`,then i want to chunk this table and change the 'status' in the table:

```
$midModel = Tname::where('status', 0);
$midModel->chunk(1, function ($rows)  {
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   Tname::where('id', $row->id)
        ->update([
              'status' => 1,
        ]);
}
});
```

After first row status was changed, 'chunk' will miss second row, my question is how to chunk with `where('status', 0)` and won't miss rows?
i try to put `where('status', 0)` into then chunk, but it will chunk all the rows in the table every time.

Answer (score 7):

Just came across a similar issue myself...

`chunk` works by running the query with an offset that goes up with each successive chunk, so if you are altering any columns that would change the underlying results of the query (i.e. `status` in your where clause), your offset will skip right over rows since your result set is now smaller than it was before.

The solution I came up with was to use `take` inside of a `do...while` loop, which avoids the offset issue.

```
do {
    $midModel = Tname::where('status', 0)->take(10)->get();

    foreach ($midModel as $row) {
        $row->update(['status' => 1]);
    }
while (count($midModel) > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Laravel [mentioned in their documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#chunking-results):

> If you are updating database records while chunking results, your chunk results could change in unexpected ways. If you plan to update the retrieved records while chunking, it is always best to use the **chunkById** method instead. This method will automatically paginate the results based on the record's primary key:

```php
DB::table('users')->where('active', false)
    ->chunkById(100, function ($users) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            DB::table('users')
                ->where('id', $user->id)
                ->update(['active' => true]);
        }
    });
```

---

For me this was the solution: replacing `chunk` by `chunkById`.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually doing wrong. You are **`selecting all the rows which has status 0`** & then updating individually. It will take many query where else you can set all rows **`status 1`** like this

```
Tname::update('status', 1)
```

This will update all rows regardless if there is any rows has **`status 0`**.

Comment: Thx, you may not get my points, the code in my question is just a example, i  just want to do updating rows in the body of "chunk", but can not change the 'status' used for chunk, otherwise it will step over number of chunk rows, because "chunk" function use "offset and limit" in sql and it only change the "offset" every time, because "chunk" select from first row, so filter the row which "status" was changed and "offset" move forward normally leads the missing rows. Now, i know we can not do "update" in the body of "chunk" when the updating column is used for "chunk".

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

This code will **update** all row **status** which value is 0 to 1

```
Tname::where('status', 0)->update(['status' => 1]);
```